# How I can search rows in a datatable with a searchstring?

Tags: c#, listview, datatable, datarow

I want to search rows in my `DataTable`.

I've tried this:

```
 protected void imggastsuche_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            string searchstring = txtgastsuche.Text;

            DataTable tb = DataBaseManager.GetDataTable(mysqlconnectionstring);

            DataRow[] foundRows = tb.Select("FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,NAME,COMPANY,TIMEFROM,TIMETO,CREATOR Like '%" + searchstring + "%'");

            tb = foundRows.CopyToDataTable();

            this.ListView.DataSource = tb;
            this.ListView.DataBind();

        }
```

But I have an error in my string.

What can I do if I want to search these columns?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You get the error because the parameter to `Select` is the *filterExpression* and you have passed all columns. Understand the filterExpression as a `WHERE` clause in sql. You want all columns but you want to filter by just one. You get all columns anyway since they are all part of the `DataTable`/`DataView` so you don't need to list them explicitely.

You could either use the [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx), [`DatView.RowFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) methods or [`LINQ-to-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx):

LINQ-To-DataSet (which i prefer):

```
var filtered = tb.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<String>("CREATOR").Contains(searchstring));
```

ADO.NET(`DataTable.Select`):

```
DataRow[] filteredRows = tb.Select("CREATOR LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%'");
```

ADO.NET(`DataView.RowFilter`):

```
 tb.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CREATOR LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%'";
```

---

If you want to search for this `string` in any column instead:

```
DataRow[] filteredRows = tb.Select("FIRSTNAME LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%' OR LASTNAME LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%' OR NAME LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%' OR COMPANY LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%' OR CREATOR LIKE '%" + searchstring + "%'");
```

The same with Linq:

```
var filtered = tb.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<String>("FIRSTNAME").Contains(searchstring)
           ||   r.Field<String>("LASTNAME").Contains(searchstring))
           ||   r.Field<String>("NAME").Contains(searchstring)
           ||   r.Field<String>("COMPANY").Contains(searchstring)
           ||   r.Field<String>("CREATOR").Contains(searchstring));
```

Comment: but I want to search in all columns :(

Comment: @Tarasov: You want all columns but you want to filter by one, you get all columns anyway since they are all part of the `DataTable`/`DataView`.

Comment: I want to search every column to this searchstring. I thought I can dothis :(

Answer (score 9):

If some one else needs return specifically a DataTable you can use the code below:

```
DataTable dtResult= tb.Select("CREATOR LIKE '%"+searchstring+"%'").CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 5):

I just made a **extension method** to the DataTable class for this.
It returns a new Datatable containing only the rows you want.

```
public static DataTable SearchInAllColums(this DataTable table, string keyword, StringComparison comparison)
{
    if(keyword.Equals(""))
    {
        return table;
    }
    DataRow[] filteredRows = table.Rows
           .Cast<DataRow>()
           .Where(r => r.ItemArray.Any(
           c => c.ToString().IndexOf(keyword, comparison) >= 0))
           .ToArray();

    if (filteredRows.Length == 0)
    {
        DataTable dtTemp = table.Clone();
        dtTemp.Clear();
        return dtTemp ;
    }
    else
    {
        return filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
DataTable dataTable = getData();
dataTable.SearchInAllColums(Keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could build the query you are going to use in the select.

```
            if(TextBoxCusName.Text != "")
            {
                query = "CustomerName LIKE '%" + TextBoxCusName.Text.Trim()+"%' AND ";
            }
            if(TextBoxCusContact.Text != "")
            {
                query = query + "CustomerNo LIKE '%" + TextBoxCusContact.Text.Trim() + "%' AND ";
            }
            if(TextBoxVehicleNo.Text != "")
            {
                query = query + "VehicleNo LIKE '%" + TextBoxVehicleNo.Text.Trim()+"%'";
            }
            if(query.EndsWith("AND "))
            {
                query = query.Remove(query.Length - 4);
            }
            DataRow[] result = dataCustomerAndVehicle.Select(query);
```

this equivalent to

```
select * from dataCustomerAndVehicle where CustomerName LIKE '%...%' AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Static method for search any column

```
public static DataTable SearchInAllColums(DataTable table, string keyword)
{
    StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

    if (keyword.Equals(""))
    {
        return table;
    }

    DataRow[] filteredRows = table.Rows
           .Cast<DataRow>()
           .Where(r => r.ItemArray.Any(
           c => c.ToString().IndexOf(keyword, comparison) >= 0))
           .ToArray();

    if (filteredRows.Length == 0)
    {
        DataTable dtTemp = table.Clone();
        dtTemp.Clear();
        return dtTemp;
    }
    else
    {
        return filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
    }
}
```